# If conductors have "free electrons", why they don't get "discharged" when grounded?

Tags: electrostatics

This question is about understanding the term "free electrons" in conductors.

Online one can find that free electrons concentration for copper is around $8.5\cdot10^{28} 
\space m^{-3}$. If we have a copper rod of length $L=1\space m$ and cross section area $A=10^{-4} \space m^2$ then the charge from free electrons is $Q=n\cdot e \cdot LA=8.5\cdot10^{24}\space e=1.36\cdot 10^{6}\space C$. Which is quite a lot. Let's say I take the rod and I touch the home wall radiator with the rod and well... nothing happens pretty much.

What are the holes in my reasoning? What kind of misconceptions might I have?

Comment: You have as many negatively charged electrons as positively charged protons in order to make the material neutral. Those electrons have no desire to run away to ground from the positive charges.

Comment: "Free" is maybe a misleading word. The [_valence electrons_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_electron) in a [_body of metal_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding) are free to move about within the metal object, but they are not always so free to pack up and leave it.

Comment: Free electrons does not mean excess electrons. Instead it just means electrons that are free to wander around without being bound to any particular positive charge; but they still to be there to match those positive charges on the average.

Answer (score 1):

"Free electrons" in a conductor means that the electrons are mobile, i.e., they are able to randomly move about among the protons in the conductor without being anchored to any particular proton.

An electrical discharge involves the collective motion of the electrons in a particular direction. This generally requires the introduction of an electric field to exert a force on the electrons in the direction opposite that of the field. In the absence of such a field there is nothing that would cause an electrical discharge.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The copper rod will contain an equal amount of positive charge due to the protons in the nuclei of the copper atoms. Each copper atom has an equal number of protons and electrons, which makes the atom electrically neutral. Since all the atoms are electrically neutral, the rod will be as well, unless something is done to force charge on or off the rod. For example, if you touch one terminal if a battery to the rod, the voltage of the battery will either add or subtract a tiny amount of charge from the rod, depending on which terminal is used.